# Understanding `\list` and `\item[]`

Tags: macros, formatting, lists

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text) question, the following solution was offered for creating an indented environment.

```
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

I want to understand this code better.

First of all, I think I get the basic idea of `\def` and `\let`, and the difference between them. But does anyone have a good reference for the finer points of these?

Also, I see this `\list{}` command popping up in a lot of places, and I don't understand what it does. Googling didn't bring a lot of help. And what is this `item[]` thing doing?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47057/use-of-trivlist-and-list-in-defining-environments/47069#47069

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi David, thanks for your comment. Maybe it would help if I had a reference for the `\list{}` command and what it does. Then I could figure out how it accomplishes what you say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Use of \trivlist and \list in defining environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47057/use-of-trivlist-and-list-in-defining-environments/47069#47069)

`\list` is the command that underlies `\begin{enumerate}` and `\begin{itemize}` (hence its name), but also `\begin{quote}` `\begin{verbatim}` , `\begin{center}` and more or less all display environments in latex. `\item[]` is the usual `\item` command as used in `enumerate`

The `changemargin` environment shown, like the standard `center`and `quote` environments is implemented as a one item list with no visible item label (hence the `\item[]` command in the environment definition).

Using the list mechanism is a convenient way to control the paragraph shape and the spacing before and after the environment.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why `{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}` is surrounded by its own set of braces?

Comment: @EricAuld they are not a group, that is the second argument of `\list` and that macro injects them to set up the inner paragraph setting, after it has handled other details of the setup.