# Can anyone help me to explain the \list, \endlist and \item \commands in the newenvironment

Tags: lists

```
\newenvironment{resumelist}[1]
  {{\noindent\normalfont\bfseries #1}

   \list{}{\labelwidth\z@ 
        %% what's the meaning of the command \list{}
           \leftmargin 4\ccwd  
           \itemindent -2\ccwd   
           \listparindent\itemindent}%  
   \item\relax}
```

% what's the meaning of the command \item and what is the function of \relax

```
  {\endlist} %%why not \end{list}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idiom is used for lots of standard latex environments such as `center` and `quote`. They are one-item lists, like `enumerate`  so

`\list` is the basic list constructor that makes `enumerate` or `itemize` but as there is just one item (the content of the environment) `\item` is supplied and the `\relax` does nothing but prevents `\item` looking ahead and treating a `[` at the start of the text as an optional argument.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Carlisle for you kind reply, I am still unclear, could you tell me where can I find the explanation of \list, I searched almost two days on the internet about this command, but find nothing useful explanation, meanwhile, can you explian why not using \begin{list} and why this environment ends up with \endlist, why not \end{list}?

Comment: @PeterYang `texdoc source2e` will give you the documented sources of latex. Using `\foo` `\endfoo` is an optimisation common when defining one environment in terms of another. `\newnvironment{abc}{}{}` defines `\abc` and `\endabc` so you can call them directly in some contexts

Comment: @PeterYang https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332063/understanding-list-and-item/332067#332067

Comment: \newenvironment{resumelist}[1]
  {{\noindent\normalfont\bfseries #1}

   \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth\z@ 
        %% what's the meaning of the command \list{}
           \leftmargin 4\ccwd  
           \itemindent -2\ccwd   
           \listparindent\itemindent}%  
   \item\relax}
 {\endlist}

Comment: @PeterYang that comment just repeats the question, it sets the left margin to 4 times the command `\ccwd`  which will be a length defined somewhere in code you have not shown. and the indent for the first line of text is set to -2 times that length (ie the start of the first line is shifted left)

Comment: I have updated  \list{}  with \begin{list}, and \endlist with \end{list}, it also works, it is easy to understand, however, could you tell me  what the comand \item\relax mean? does it mean that \begin{list} and \end{list} has only just one item in the content of its list environment ? Am I right?