# When are blank lines allowed in a tikzcd environment?

Tags: errors, tikz-cd

Leaving a line empty in a bare `tikzcd` environment (as below) produces a "Missing $ inserted" error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A

B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

But when I wrap the `tikzcd` environment in a `center` environment (as below), there is no compilation error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
A

B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead wrap them in a minimal compilable document.

Comment: a blank line is `\par` and `\par` is redefined by `center` environment

Answer (score 2):

Adding some detail to David's comment.

The `center` environment and other similar "display" environments use the `\trivlist` construction internally.  (I'm using David Carlisle's terminology from [Use of \trivlist and \list in defining environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47057/2693)).

So `\center` is defined as:

```
\trivlist \centering \item \relax
```

And within the definition of `\trivlist` (actually `\@trivlist`) is a redefinition of `\par` to:

```
\if@newlist \advance \par@deathcycles \@ne \ifnum \par@deathcycles >\@m
  \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }\fi
```

This effectively means that `\par` (or a blank line) doesn't behave like regular `\par` inside the `center` environment, and therefore doesn't produce the error you see when the `tikzcd` environment is inside the `center` environment.